# how to convert vlc web plugin embed element in a image using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, libvlc

**I need convert in a image the video of vlc embed , i need take a snapshot from the video is possible this?**

```
  <div id="video" style="width:400px; height:200px; background-color:red;">
    <embed type="application/x-vlc-plugin" pluginspage="http://www.videolan.org" id="vlc1" name="vlc1" toolbar="true" allowfullscreen="false" windowless="true"  width=100% height=100% target="http://localhost/medias/s.mp4" />
    </div>
    <input  type="button" value="Probar" onclick="prueba()">
    <div  id="photo" style="width:500px; height:300px; background-color:green;">
```

Comment: you found any solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

Taking pictures of webpages is indeed possible using html2canvas!
http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/
should work with plugins as well as anything else

Comment: I try using  html2canvas.js but no works, no take the picture to embed element.

Comment: Hmmm. Is it not possible to use the HTML5 video tag? That should work and is supported in all the most recent browsers.
For the record, VLC Media Player does have a Javascript API [link]https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:WebPlugin/ but it doesn't seem to do what you're trying to accomplish. You could try it.

Comment: I cannot use HTML5 video tag because HTML5  not support  video streaming in rtsp.Any sugestion?